# Select SUM a column and group by

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables (tblGenerator AND tblGeneratorLine). tblGenerator contains ingormation about each generator, and the tblGeneratorLine contains the rent per month per generator. I want to get a list of total RentPayd per generator in one year. I am using the code below, when I run the code I get this
error:

> In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain
>   only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = g,Zoon ]

Can any one please help.

```
internal static DataTable getRentByYear(int year)
{
    string sql = "Select SUM(l.RentPayd) AS Payd, l.GenId, g.Zoon from tblGeneratorLine AS l INNER JOIN tblGenerator AS g on l.GenId=g.GenId where l.Year=@year Group By l.GenId Order By l.GenId";

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con);
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = year;
         adp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Where the extracted SQL query is:

```
select SUM(l.RentPayd) AS Payd, l.GenId, g.Zoon
from tblGeneratorLine AS l
    INNER JOIN tblGenerator AS g on l.GenId = g.GenId
where l.Year = @year
group By l.GenId
order By l.GenId
```

Comment: `Group By` clause works only when you group by the elements you're selecting...in your case: `l.GenId` and `g.Zoon`..if you want total per year and generator...group by these two fields.

Comment: As @ElmerDantas already said, the GROUP BY is invalid. The question is now, what do you want? Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: It's pure SQL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `g.Zoon` to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
string sql = @"
SELECT   SUM(l.RentPayd) AS Payd
        ,l.GenId
        ,g.Zoon
FROM tblGeneratorLine AS l
    INNER JOIN tblGenerator AS g
        ON l.GenId = g.GenId
WHERE l.Year = @year
GROUP BY l.GenId
        ,g.Zoon
ORDER BY l.GenId
";
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, When using a group by, every field in the select that is not using an aggregation function (like `sum` for example) should be in the group by clause as well.

So, in your case you should add `g.Zoon` to the `Group By`:

```
....  Group By l.GenId, g.Zoon ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include all non-aggregated columns in the group by clause
So if grouping by g.zoon gives you the correct result then it's as simple as adding that to the group by:

```
   Group By l.GenId
   , g.Zoon
```

If not then you will need to use a CTE or subselect to get  first the sum by l.GenId and then the g.zoon for example:

```
Select T.SumPayd
, g.Zoon 
FROM tblGenerator AS g 
INNER JOIN
(   Select 
        SUM(l.RentPayd) AS SumPayd
        , l.GenId
    from tblGeneratorLine AS l 
    where l.Year=@year 
    Group By 
        l.GenId
) AS T
WHERE g.GenId = T.GenId 
Order By g.GenId
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL, you select l.GenId, g.Zoon, and Sum(l.RentPayd)

In your group by, you only have l.GenId

g.Zoon is not in your group by, and it is not an aggregate (Sum, count, max etc)

It has to be one or the other, or you can't have it in the select statement.

If you have multiple records being grouped into one line, what do you wish to do with Zoon? If they all have to be the same for the same output row, put it in the group by clause. Otherwise, you'll have to sum, max, or something, depending on what it is and what you want.